# Get Gravity forms entry ID after submitting the form in the gform_pre_send_email function

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm having trouble getting the Gravity Forms entry ID after submitting the for in the 'gform_pre_send_email' function.

In the GF log the Entry ID is visible:

```
DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::save_entry(): Saving entry. 
DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::save_entry(): **Entry record created in the database. ID: 95.** 
DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::save_entry(): Saving entry fields.
```

After setting $entry as global within the function, rgar( $entry, 'id' ) returns empty as does var_dump( $entry ). Same goes for the $form array. The $_POST array doesn't yet contain the entry ID.

Also the API returns empty: GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id ).

$wpdb->insert_id does provide a number, but it isn't the correct ID of the entry.

I've tried many options, read many posts, finished Google. It's seems such a simple quest but i'm missing out in how to handle this.

Used code:

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_send_email', 'before_email' );
function before_email( $email ) {

    global $entry;
    $entryid = rgar( $entry, 'id' );

    //DEBUGGING
    echo '<br><br>POST:<br>';
    var_dump( $_POST );
    echo '<br><br>Entry:<br>';      
    var_dump( $entry );
    echo '<br><br>';

    $pattern = "PAYMENTLINK";
    $replacement = "<a href='https://******.***/checkout/?add-to-cart=44&entryid=$entryid' target='_blank'>https://******.***/pay</a>";
    $email['message'] = str_replace($pattern, $replacement, $email['message']);

    return $email;
}
```

How to i get the entry ID of the just submitted form? Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need to set `$entry` as a global, it's already passed to the function. Can we see your code?

Comment: @johnnyd23 sure, added it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oke, many hours spend, solution found. Stupid to over see this..

Function with 1 argument:

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_send_email', 'before_email' );
function before_email( $email ) {
```

Function with 4 arguments (Note the **,10 ,4** in the add_filter):

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_send_email', 'before_email' , 10, 4 );
function before_email( $email, $message_format, $notification, $entry) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is simply the way you're trying to include the `$entryid` var within your string. You need to remove the var from the string and concatenate it instead:

```
$replacement = "<a href='https://******.***/checkout/?add-to-cart=44&entryid=".$entryid."' target='_blank'>https://******.***/pay</a>";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

EDIT

Also, you will need to pass the $entry object to your function. You're currently only passing the $email variable:

```
function before_email( $email, $message_format, $notification, $entry ) {
```

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it is still empty.

Comment: Try removing the `global $entry` line. What is the URL of the link that comes through in the email?

Comment: If i don't set $entry as global, i get: "Notice: Undefined variable: entry in..."

Comment: Gives the following error: 
Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function before_email(), 1 passed in /......./wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 288 and exactly 4 expected in /.../functions.php. Or 2 expected if i only use: function before_email( $email, $entry ) {

Comment: var_dump( $form ) is also returning NULL so i can't get the routing array either.  https://docs.gravityforms.com/notification/#usage

Comment: Are you including all 4 arguments? From that error it sounds like you're still passing just 1

Comment: yeah, getting this error (see next comment) when using:  function before_email( $email, $message_format, $notification, $entry ) {}

Comment: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function before_email(), 1 passed in /../class-wp-hook.php on line 288 and exactly 4 expected in /…./functions.php:50\nStack trace:\n#0 /…/class-wp-hook.php(288): before_email(Array)\n#1 /…/plugin.php(203): WP_Hook->apply_filters(Array, Array)\n#2 /…/gravityforms/common.php(2056): apply_filters('gform_pre_send_...', Array, 'html', Array, Array)\n#3 /../gravityforms/common.php(1825): GFCommon::send_email('XXX@ZZZZZZ...', XXXX@gm...', 'XXXX@ZZZZZZZ..', 'XXXX@ZZZZZZ...' referer: https://xxx.xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/